# Converting special characters with htmlspecialchars and htmlentities

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, html-entities

I am getting confused with injecting special characters into my database now...

For instance, I want to accept characters like this `ö`, `ù`, etc and I want to display them as they are on html such as `Löic` which is a French name.

And I thought I must convert these special characters into html entities before injecting them into database, like `&ouml;` for `ö`.

If I use `htmlspecialchars()` to convert them,

```
 Array
(
    [name] => Löic
)

if(isset($_POST['name'])) $name = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', trim($_POST['name']));
$name = htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES);
```

So it should be converted into this `L&ouml;ic` but it is not converted at all, instead as it is,

```
Löic
```

So this is what I get when I check my database, it is stored as,

```
LÃ¶ic
```

If I use `htmlentities()` to convert them,

```
$name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES);
```

then I get this,

```
L&Atilde;&para;ic
```

and it is displayed as this on my html,

```
LÃ¶ic
```

Why does it do that?? My head is going to explode! I don't know where the problem is. Please help... What shall I do to make it right?

Is it to do with `utf8_general_ci` which I set at that name column??

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want html entities in your database? Forget about htmlentities and htmlspecialchars, you don't need them. (You only need htmlspecialchars when outputing html, for escaping the reserved characters <, >, &, ', ").  Solve your encoding issue, plenty of q&a in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to convert utf8 characters with htmlentites. Sadly the function does only work on ascii chars correctly. The easiest solution is to simple store your strings in your utf8 database table and output them with only htmlspecialchars instead of htmlentities. Just be sure to set your page encoding to utf8.

Comment: thanks. now it is fine with your suggestion - but why htmlspecialchars doesn't convert them, instead htmlentities does?? I believe that my page encoding is utf8 - <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: the problem with conversion is, that htmlentities works on single bytes, but in utf8 some special characters actually consist of two bytes - so you type ö, but htmlentities is not smart enough to interpret it as a multibyte character and instead sees two characters - i.e. Ã and ¶

Answer (score 1):

Also you can simple do:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars( $text );
$text = mysql_escape_string( $text );
```