# reading a file with the right encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I have a txt file where, if I open with a standart text editor as notepad or scite, I can read strings like these :

```
Artist1 – Title 1
Artist2 – Title 2
```

Than I open it with my PHP script and I read the lines :

```
$tracklistFile_name=time().rand(1, 1000).".".pathinfo($_FILES['tracklistFile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(((pathinfo($tracklistFile_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='txt')) && (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tracklistFile']['tmp_name'], 'import/'.$tracklistFile_name))) {
    $fileArray=file('import/'.$tracklistFile_name, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $fileArray=array_values(array_filter($fileArray, "trim"));

    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($fileArray); $i++) {
        echo $fileArray[$i]."<br />";
    }
}
```

and...WOW... i get this result :

```
Artist1 � Title1 
Artist2 � Title2
```

??? What are those symbol? I think the encoding fail. 
The symbol are so wrong that I can't insert them on database, neither with `mysql_real_escape_string()`. In fact I get this error when I try to insert them :

```
Incorrect string value: '\x96 Titl...' for column 'atl' at row 1
```

How can I resolve this problem? Suggestions?

**EDIT**

Tried to add utf8_encode() before insert/add these strings : now the Insert don't fail, but the result is :

```
Artist1  Title1 
Artist2  Title2
```

So i've lost information. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786527/php-mysql-converting-special-characters-with-htmlspecialchars-and-htmlentities

Comment: Is not a problem of print the file, the problme is get/read the chars from txt in the right way, using utf8 if possible!

Comment: as I see, you have successfully read this symbol, and problem, ATM, exactly in inserting into database. Try to escape string by mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: Uhm, I don't think to have read the char correctly. As i wrote on the topic, I already used mysql_real_escape_string() man, but it fails.

Comment: until you got no errors about reading file, file was read correctly.

Comment: Yes, was the encoding that fail. Now with utf8_encode() i partially resolved the problem : I still lost some characters!

Comment: Maybe table was created without utf-8 support. See CREATE TABLE code for this table (no need to paste it here, except last line with "DEFAULT CHARSET"). Or try use query "SET NAMES utf-8" before inserting, if table was created with utf-8.

Comment: yes, It's all utf8 : browser, connection, tables (charset/collation)

Comment: Well... So don't use that function (utf8_encode) :) Use htmlentites (with ENT_COMPAT) or $str = str_replace('\\x96',' - ', $str); :)

Comment: Heheh yeah but I need a method that works with every kind of special chars, not only with that one :)

Comment: I see a \x96.  Is that hex 96?  U+0096 is START OF GUARDED AREA. I think you have some ugly legacy encoding.  If it’s Apple MacRoman, then 0x96  ⇒  U+00F1  ‹ñ›  \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE}.  If it’s  legacy Micro$loth CodiePagey 0x4E4, then  0x96 is U+2013 ‹–› \N{EN DASH}. Use `iconv -t UTF-8` to get rid of the ugly legacy encoding, whatever weirdo thingie it is.

Comment: Uhm, how can I get rid about that legacy encoding when I read a file? I have done a script where every kind of user can import this txt : I need a sort of wall between read it and insert it (i won't insert these kind of data, or at least do the right encoding)

Answer (score 9):

You should read [Joel Spolsky's article on UTF-8 and encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Your problem almost definitely stems from an encoding mismatch, your first job is to figure out where this mismatch is occurring, your problem could be in a bunch of different places.

1) your php code could be reading input using an incorrect encoding (if you are trying to read in iso-8859, but the source file is encoded some other way)

2) your php code could be writing output using an incorrect encoding

3) whatever you are using to read the output (your browser) could be set to a different encoding than the bytes you are writing.

once you figure out which of the 3 places is causing your problem, you can figure out how to fix it by understanding what your source encoding is, and how to read/write using that source encoding instead of another encoding (which your system has probably set as the default).

EDIT: not knowing php well, it looks like you could use [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and possibly also [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

Comment: But how can I know the source encoding from a txt file? txt files could be written in many ways, I need to understand which encoding is for each file and read it due to the encoding... dunno if this is possible in real time :)

Comment: in general, things will be much easier if you use an agreed upon convention like UTF-8 for encoding

Comment: But when? When I read the file? The problem is when I read it; the web application is already on utf8... the characters on file aren't utf8, so I need to convert it on utf8 (I think). How can I do this?

Comment: yes, when you read the file in and convert it to a string, you are using a character encoding. I don't know php well, but it's probably your file() function that is doing this.

Comment: that's what I hoped, but in fact I see there isn't any way to encode the file when I reading it! Found that utf_encode() function, but in fact some characters fail... don't know why :(

Comment: I edited my post, but try mb_convert_encoding or similar? you should be able to google this. but the first step is to understand the root cause of the problem, is it definitely your source file?

Comment: Yeah it is from only specific text! Others seems to work perfectly :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this: `$str = str_replace('\\x', '&#', $str);`

Comment: Yes but always for that characters, not for other further characters. There isnt the whole control of what you are encoding...

Comment: For that way to encode utf-symbols. Any other ways should not create any problems (if utf-8 are supported by db).