# Wrong characters in some e-mail clients

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

Have you seen an error like this? Using some email clients the characters appear to be different. I used the red squares to highlight the wrong words and the green squares for other words that are ok

The difference between them is that the words with special characters that are OK are written in the email template, whereas the wrong ones come from the database.

I tried sending this email to Hotmail and Gmail. In Hotmail they look different if they go to the Spam box. The special characters in the red squares are replaced by a '?', the others become a black a symbol

[image]

Do any of you know what is going on? Do you know how to fix it? Is it a problem in the client or the way the message is being encoded?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try to save the template again in another encoding, like UTF-8?

Comment: with or without BOM? btw you mean the template or the script where I put both template and databsase data together?

Comment: I'd try without first.

Comment: they all seem to be in UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: Then I really don't know, but I think you might find some help from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5796358/1697755

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps below to see if that could help:

1)  From Outlook, click File from the top left > Options > Advanced
2) Scroll down until you see "International Options"
3) Check "Automatically Select Encoding for Outgoing..."
4) Select UTF-8 encoding from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing (or setting) the encoding in the html template. If it doesn't help, convert characters to html entities - that works in all email clients.